# PDO insert error without error display

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

Hy, 
I've got some errors with this pdo insert:

```
            $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO matches (teamA, teamB, start, lenght) VALUES (:teamA, :teamB, :start, :length)");
            $query->execute(array(
                ':teamA' => $_GET['teamA'],
                ':teamB' => $_GET['teamB'],
                ':start' => $_GET['start'],
                ':lenght' => $_GET['length']
            ));
```

The pdo doesn't trow any error, but not insert my database this line

I call the php file with jQuery this way:

```
$('.load').load('request.php?type=save&table=matches&teamA=' + homeTeam.children("select").val() + '&teamB=' + awayTeam.children("select").val() + '&start=' + start.children("select").val() + '&length=' + length.children("select").val());
```

The jQuery is working fine, I tested it, but the pdo not, plesa help me.

Comment: Are you sure you've properly spelled the word "length"? You may have a typo somewhere. Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so. Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php may also help if you have other errors.

Comment: You made an edit changing `lenght` to `length` for certain things, but not for your column name `lenght` and in `':lenght' =>`

Comment: THe `:lenght` in execute does not match the `:length` in prepare

Comment: ...that's where `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` would signal that ^

Comment: You post a question, we give you reasons why your code is failing and now it's up to you to interact with us and tell us what's going on, or not. We have no idea what's happening at this point. Don't be afraid to type something in the comments box.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Eh it looks like there is already an answer,thanks.

Comment: @Mihai It's wrong and for a few reasons. You and I were here first ;-) and we both saw it and commented first. Please do. You have my blessing.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  HAhahahah oh god.Feel free to post your answer your were the first to notice the errors

Comment: @Mihai *Done like dinner* ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm putting in an answer for this.

Your column and binds do not match.

You have `lenght` and `length`

They should all read as `length`, it's been mispelled.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO matches (teamA, teamB, start, length)  
 VALUES (:teamA, :teamB, :start, :length)");

    $query->execute(array(
        ':teamA' => $_GET['teamA'],
        ':teamB' => $_GET['teamB'],
        ':start' => $_GET['start'],
        ':length' => $_GET['length']
    ));
```

Having checked for errors would have signaled the error(s)

Add the following right after the connection is opened:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Well, at least putting the error out to the end user. Reporting should always be done and should always be checked and should always be accounted for ;-) @Fred -ii- *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: @JayBlanchard ...and should always have a stiff drink to one's side at all times; whether it be a 20yr. Scotch or a double Espresso - *Mornin' Sam*

Answer (score 0):

Try to track execution errors:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO matches (teamA, teamB, start, lenght) VALUES (:teamA, :teamB, :start, :length)");

        if ($query->execute(array(

                    ':teamA' => $_GET['teamA'],
                    ':teamB' => $_GET['teamB'],
                    ':start' => $_GET['start'],
                    ':lenght' => $_GET['length']
                )) ) {
    echo 'Query executed succsessfully!';
    } else {
        echo 'Failed to execute query! Error: '.$query->errorInfo();
}
```